# Animation effect to buttons in linear layout

Tags: android, animation

I have a floating action button and a linear layout containing five buttons.On clicking of floating action button, i am making linear layout visible or invisible.I want to add animations to those buttons on click of floating action button.The animation should be like on clicking of fab,first button should be visible of linear layout and then second button should be visible,then third,then fourth and so on.I have tried adding the following animation but it doesn't quite work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.4"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        />  </set>
```

Please help

Comment: You have to animate another button on animation end of first button.

Comment: check this https://codeforandroid.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/android-animation-animating-multiple-views-one-after-the-other/

Comment: if you want to display buttons inside the linear layout one by one use a handles and specifying your time delay make the button visible one by one